# Why $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is used instead of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$?

Tags: group-theory

Since both notations are the same, why $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is used instead of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: But it is not always used instead.

Comment: Wherever both apply, the group with $\oplus$ is "nicer" than the group with $\times$.  So, one may be inclined to use $\oplus$ wherever it's possible to do so.